# Issue with conda env while using uwsgi

Tags: python, django, linux, anaconda, uwsgi

I'm trying to run django server with uwsgi using anaconda python on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.
I've created a conda environment and installed all the dependencies.

If I run the django server in dev(i.e python manage.py runserver), it's working without any issues. But, when I run it with uwsgi, I'm getting "ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref stackoverflow"

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  File "/opt/myproj/venvs/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
  File "/opt/myproj/venvs/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 5, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/opt/myproj/venvs/api/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/opt/myproj/venvs/api/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

I've set the path to anaconda

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/baji/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/baji/anaconda2/bin

$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/opt/myproj/venvs/api/bin/python
```

The uwsgi command that I'm trying is

```
$ /opt/myproj/venvs/api/bin/uwsgi -H /opt/myproj/venvs/api/ -i /opt/myproj/api/wsgi.ini
```

This is the wsgi.ini file

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:application
master = true
processes = 1
chmod-socket = 666
socket = /tmp/api.sock
check-static = ./static
wsgi-file = wsgi.py
touch-reload = /tmp/api.txt
buffer-size = 65535
post-buffering = 1
listen = 65535
vacuum = true
max-requests = 1000
stats = 3032
stats-http = true
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out the problem. After installing the conda version of uwsgi the issue has gone.

I had to update these in order to run the django server with uwsgi

```
conda install -c conda-forge uwsgi
conda install pip
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Why would you install the packages using pip? Is it really necessary here?